# Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content

Tags: html, css, gwt

This error is driving me nuts in GWT. I can't seem to fix it so I can improve the page speed of my pages. This is the error that I get.

```
 Your page has 2 blocking CSS resources. This causes a delay in rendering your page.

 None of the above-the-fold content on your page could be rendered without waiting for the following resources to load. Try to defer or asynchronously load blocking resources, or inline the critical portions of those resources directly in the HTML.
 Optimize CSS Delivery of the following:

http://www.example.com/files/myfile.css
http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can load them asynchronously from GWT using [StyleInjector](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/dom/client/StyleInjector.html).

Comment: This will be a solution as long as you don't mind if on the first view your visitors will get before your CSS file will be fully loaded will look horrible because your pages will not be styled.